# Grouping and summing quantity lines with same product

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have this function it filters in all selected MO's raw material lines, and then creates a report that is displayed in tree view.

But I have one problem, there can be allot lines with the same product. So my goal is to group all these lines and display them then just in one line with summed quantity.

Can someone help me with this?

```py
class RawMaterialReport(models.Model):
    _name = 'raw.material.report'
    _description = 'Raw Material Report'

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product', required=False)
    code = fields.Char(string='Code', required=True, readonly=True)
    total_qty = fields.Float(string='Total Qty', digits=(6, 2), readonly=True)
    virtual_qty = fields.Float(string='Forcasted Qty', digits=(6, 2), readonly=True)
    origin = fields.Char(string='Origin', required=True, readonly=True)
    production_id = fields.Many2one('mrp.production')


@api.multi
def open_raw_materials(self):
    self.search([]).unlink()
    mrp_productions = self._context.get('active_ids')
    mrp_production = self.env['mrp.production'].browse(mrp_productions)
    products_without_default_code = mrp_production.mapped('move_raw_ids').filtered(
        lambda x: not x.product_id.default_code
    )

    raws = mrp_production.mapped('move_raw_ids').sorted(
        key=lambda r: r.product_id.default_code
    )

    for r in raws:
        vals = {
            'product_id': r.product_id.id,
            'code': r.product_id.default_code,
            'total_qty': r.product_id.qty_available,
            'virtual_qty': r.product_id.virtual_available,
            'origin': r.reference,
            'production_id': r.raw_material_production_id.id,
        }
        self.create(vals)
```

Comment: What about a group by in the tree/list view? Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: No, because there is another functionality , that user will select lines and create purchase orders from them, so that's why lines should be grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the record directly, keep them in dictionary grouped by product ID and when ever you find that the product all ready have a record just sum its
quantity.

```py
@api.multi
def open_raw_materials(self):
    self.search([]).unlink()
    mrp_productions = self._context.get('active_ids')
    mrp_production = self.env['mrp.production'].browse(mrp_productions)
    products_without_default_code = mrp_production.mapped('move_raw_ids').filtered(
        lambda x: not x.product_id.default_code
    )

    raws = mrp_production.mapped('move_raw_ids').sorted(
        key=lambda r: r.product_id.default_code
    )

    # to group by product
    recs = {}
    for r in raws:
        product_id = self.product_id.id
        if product_id in recs:
            # here just update the quantities or any other fields you want to sum
            recs[product_id]['product_uom_qty'] += self.product_id.product_uom_qty 
        else:
            # keep the record in recs
            recs[product_id] = {
                'product_id': r.product_id.id,
                'code': r.product_id.default_code,
                'total_qty': r.product_id.product_uom_qty,
                'virtual_qty': r.product_id.virtual_available,
                'origin': r.reference,
                'production_id': r.raw_material_production_id.id,
            }
    for vals in recs.values():
        # create records this will create a record by product
        self.create(vals)
```

Comment: yeh it's should be r.product_uom_qty instead of product_id.qty_available, Thank you for your answer, and btw recs[product_id][total_qty] gives me Unresolved reference 'total_qty'

Comment: and ValueError: <class 'TypeError'>: "'int' object is not iterable" while evaluating
'action = model.open_raw_materials()

Comment: Ooops it's a dictionary use `items() or values()`  stupid mistake, `for vals in recs.values()`, create and write expects dictionary not integer (Ids of record that are keys of recs)

Comment: and for the Unresolved reference I forget to put the key between the quotes, it's String value, but the interpreter thing i'm using a variable sorry for that, was to late yesterday. `recs[product_id]['your_field'] += self.your_field` and you are creating a record in the same model? `self.create()` I really don't understand what you are doing

Comment: I'm creating records from MO orders tree view from action, but I did sorted it out, works fine now. Thanks, good stuff.